# "Enabling ... during" or "enabling ... through"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I want to say that:

> I worked on enabling Marketing and Engineering teams **during** several
>   product launches.

Is "during" the right word to use here? Should it be "through"? How do I know which is the right preposition to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you probably mean to say "I worked to enable" not "I worked on enabling", or even simpler "I enabled".  The problem with "worked on enabling" is it has the connotation of something that took a long time to complete, like:

- I worked on the Hoover Dam.
- I'm working on my anger issues; I've worked on them and seen improvement.
- I worked on the staff of a newspaper for my first job.

You don't want to convey the idea that it took you a long time to enable the teams so that's why the alternatives I suggest are preferable.

Now examining:

- I enabled Marketing and Engineering teams during several product launches, versus
- I enabled Marketing and Engineering teams through several product launches

The first version, using "during", connotes that this work was periodic, that there would be a product launch, and you would need to shift gears and move into enabling mode, and then the launch would end, and you would switch to a different type of work for a period.  The second version, using "through", connotes that this work was continuous, that another product would probably start being launched even before the first was done launching, and therefore year-round you were focused on enabling these teams participating in the product launches. I don't think either word has a better connotation to it or would be more helpful on a resume than the other, so you probably just want to use whichever word is more accurate.

Comment: But how do you enable a team?  You could enable a team to do something.  But wouldn't it be better to facilitate the team's work?  Brillig, if a question isn't well posed, it's best not to answer it.

Comment: Enabling a team is common business language.  I didn't introduce the term - it was in the original question - I just suggested making it less wordy.  Also, there are many cases I can think of where enable would be appropriate and not facilitate - if he works in IT, he may enable the engineering and marketing teams by providing them IT support but he's not going to put on his engineering cap and start facilitating their engineering analysis.  It seems your understanding is mostly academic and you're struggling with how business terminology is actually used, but that's no reason to downvote me.

Comment: Thank you. In face of what you said, "during" is what I was looking for. Do you know a good place with all the different prepositions' meaning?

Comment: Interestingly, no.  I think a lot of native English speakers probably look at this and instantly think that it's just too easy of a question as to when to use during and when to use through.  But I'm pretty handy with Google and when I was writing my answer I ran some searches to find a resource I could cite and I didn't find any that I would recommend.  It seems that this is a comparison that many people overlook, perhaps not realizing it could be useful to people with fairly evolved language skills but who are not native speakers or otherwise just have a question about this.

Comment: @JohnAssymptoth - I googled and found a list with example sentences that might be helpful: http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/prepositions/list-of-common-prepositions.html

Comment: @aparente001 but there's no explanation of how the prepositions should work, and for one of the two words he was interested in, "during", the sentence doesn't even use during as a preposition - it gives:  "During- We’ve added before and after to the list, during completes the trifecta."
I'm not sure there's any useful information on this site for how to use "during" as opposed to "through" which is why I didn't list this site or other similar sites.  However, I'd be interested if you could find a site that is (much) more helpful than this one.

Comment: @Brillig - Is this better?  http://www.learn-english-today.com/lessons/lesson_contents/grammar/prepositions.html  (My google words: prepositions english examples list)

Comment: @aparente001 definitely a better site!  However, note the two words the questioner above wanted to contrast were "during" and "through" and "during" is not even included on this site!  It was surprising to me that there wasn't an easier to find resource to compare these two prepositions.  Even the sites you're finding are just example sentences not any deep explanation of why one preposition might be ok in some instances and not in others, or when "during" is more appropriate than "through", but even just looking for example sentences you're struggling to find a decent site!

Comment: @Brillig - Well, those are very good criteria you've found, for judging the usefulness of a resource.  Why don't you ask a question about this?  Possibly ELL would be a good place to ask.  I hope you'll notify me here if you find a good one.

Comment: @aparente001 will do!  I've been looking for a decent question to ask so I can get the "student" badge!